# Combine different tables with time in minutes columns

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have the following data (just a snippet). They start at 0 min and end at 65 min.

```
      R.Time (min)  Intensity 215  Intensity 260  Intensity 280
0          0.00000              0              0              0
1          0.01067              0              0              0
2          0.02133              0              0              0
3          0.03200              0              0              0
```

and

```
              Time     %B     c B   c KCl
0            16.01   0.00  0.0000    0.00
1            16.01   0.00  0.0000    0.00
2            17.00   0.85  0.0085    4.25
3            18.00   1.70  0.0170    8.50
```

How can I create a dataframe with the time [min] column and all other columns at the correct row for that time. So I need to tell pandas the time column and how to merge and then it sorts the rows? But I also needs to combine rows, when the time is the same.

Comment: Hmmm, if need match columns with times, need `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time')`. But problem is values are floats, so many values not match, because precision. Maybe [merge_asof](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-asof) should help, but it is a bit different.

Comment: Can you change data with desired output?

Comment: I actually noticed, that it doesn´t really matter to combine rows in that case. Just sorting would be enough probably

Comment: Do you think `df = df.sort_values('Time')` ?